# numberOfRowsInSection: for a specific attribute

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I have a UITableView that is populated with data from core data and I currently have it set up so that it adjusts the size of the table based on the number of objects in an entity. My problem is that I know have two attributes in this entity. Now the tableview has a bunch of extra cells because it is creating one for everything in the entity, not just creating one per object in a specific attribute. So I would like to set `numberOfRowsInSection:` based on amount of objects in an attribute, not the whole entity. How would I do this?

How I am currently doing it:

```
id  sectionInfo =
[[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
```

EDIT:

This is what I have tried:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
//    id  sectionInfo =
//    [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
//    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FeedEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"imageData != nill"];
    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    id  sectionInfo =
    [[theFetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

}
```

But this results in this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a fetch request with sort descriptors'
```

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "entity" and "attribute"?

Comment: So I have like "feedentity" and in that entity I have two attributes like "picture" and "string" in core data @nhgrif

Comment: @matthew Can you create a simpler analogy. I dont understand your question. Please explain what your current problem is, what result you're getting and what you would like the output to be instead.

Comment: So currently I have a table populated with text from core data and it creates a cell for each string. I then added an image to appear by each string in the cell. I would like it to still just create one cell per string but it is now creating one cell per string and one cell per image so I am getting double the amount of cells I want @Pavan

Comment: @matthew Ok, well thats an easy solve. Will there always be an image for every single string? Why not just return the yourStringDataArray.length in the `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method? This way you will only get the amount of cells needed to display your total amount of strings in your array.

Answer (score 0):

so you have one entity with two attributes. And you need to filter the objects to show for the tableview. I think you need to use NSFetchRequest and NSPredicate to filter your objects by checking the attribute of your object.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [your context];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FeedEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"imageData = nil"];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"text" ascending:NO]];
NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
```

Comment: How would I go about this?

Comment: I'm just a little confused with what to put in the text part of `fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"image = nil"];`

Comment: Ok so I am getting `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a fetch request with sort descriptors'` with this implemented. I added above what I am doing.

Comment: Yeah, add your sort descriptor as well. I assume it is called "text". You can change it to suit your needs.

Comment: so why do I have to do sort and everything when all I need is the number of items in an entity. The images are displaying and everything fine. The only problem is the amount of cells being created.

Comment: and what would I put in the predicate because after adding this, the table has no cells

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well thats an easy solve. Will there always be an image for every single string? Why not just return the `yourStringDataArray.length` in the `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method? This way you will only get the amount of cells needed to display your total amount of strings in your array.